# ORA-00907 when quering from my Java application but works fine in SQL Developer

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper, ora-00907

My query that I put into a prepared statement is:

```
select * 
  from ( select seq, audit_ts, message_type
           from log2 
          where 1 = 1 
            and message_type in ('SOURCE', 'DEST') 
          order by seq desc ) 
 where ROWNUM <= ?
```

When I run the query in my application, I get:

> java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

**EDIT:** Here is the java executing the query. I am trying to return a set of search results, so the prefix contains the SELECT statement and then I can have any number of suffixes (in this excerpt "AUDIT_LOG_SEARCH2") which are the parameterized WHERE clauses based on the user search:

```
StringBuffer query = new StringBuffer(300);
query.append(dbAdapter.getQuery("AUDIT_LOG_ENTRY_PREFIX"));
query.append(dbAdapter.getQuery("AUDIT_LOG_SEARCH2"));

// Insert parameters to complete the sql prepared statement 
PreparedStatement ps = _dbConn.prepareStatement(query.toString());
ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
```

But the query runs fine when I run it separately in SQL Developer. The query was originally created for Postgres, then updated for Oracle. Any tips?

Comment: Don't think any of these are relevant, but: are `seq` and `seq_num` different columns; and what value are you setting for the bind variable; and how are you executing it, as `execute` or `executeQuery`? Might be helpful to show the Java code around this.

Comment: That's perfectly good Oracle, so probably the problem lies in your Java code. Could you post how you're building the query? I'm assuming it's a bunch of potential conditions (the `WHERE 1=1` is something I've done in similar situations), but if there aren't too many can you post the whole chunk?

Comment: It looks like the logic that builds the query is in the `getQuery` method. Rather than chase that down, could you just print out or log the value of `query.toString()` after the `query.append(dbAdapter.getQuery("AUDIT_LOG_SEARCH2"))` statement? Then check to make sure it's what you think it is.

Comment: @EdGibbs Yes, the SQL query posted above is what is contained in `query`

Comment: Do the strings you're `append`ing have spaces - have you output the actual query string you're running to make sure it looks like you think? I'm thinking `where 1 = 1and message_type in ('SOURCE', 'DEST')`, missing a space and becoming invalid?

Comment: Sorry @yellavon, I didn't realize that what you posted was straight from `query.toString()` so sorry about the runaround. I'd look into Alex's suggestion first - he's right so often that it's scary. If that doesn't get you anywhere I still think he's on the right track and it's a character we can't see that's causing the problem, in which case a look at `dbAdapter.getQuery` would be very helpful.

Comment: @AlexPoole I have logged a completely built query that did not have any user parameters in it, copied it directly from the log into SQL Developer and it works in SQL Developer but still ORA-00907 error in my application.

Comment: OK, good to have that clarity, sorry if it seems like going over the same ground again but wanted to remove any ambiguity from that. Have you tried running that output string directly as a fixed string from Java to see if it works, bypassing the builder?

Comment: I don't see any `ps.setInt(1, ...)` call in your Java code. If you prepare a statement you have to provide a value for the parameter.

Comment: I'm trying to think of something that would cause this error (like a non-breaking space in the `where` clause) but not appear in the output, and be translated to a normal space on copy/paste, but I haven't come up with anything yet. Maybe it depends how you view the log, or is a character set/locale mismatch, or... well, just guessing really. Short of dumping the `query` character by character with `Character.getNumericValue()` and looking for anything out of the ordinary I'm not sure what to suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @AlexPoole and @EdGibbs comments, I decided to add a bunch more debug statements. It turns out the method was being recursively called with a different sql "suffix" later on in the program if certain conditions were met. The suffix was not updated with the necessary parenthesis for the new ROWNUM wrapping the statement. So although the ORA-00907 can be thrown for many different formatting problems, it was in fact a right parenthesis that was causing me problems :P

The prefix and suffix seems like a weird pattern in this code base for creating sql queries. I'm thinking of getting rid of this and refactoring so queries don't have to be built like that. Any advice??

So for anyone else who runs into this Oracle error, I would suggest logging the sql statement you are generating and play around with it in SQL Developer. If it works in there, but not in your application, your code is probably doing something funky :P

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the variables into the preparedStatement before executing.

```
PreparedStatement ps = _dbConn.prepareStatement(query.toString());
ps.setInt(1, 10);
```

Please post what `query.toString()` gives you if that doesn't work. Not `query`, but `query.toString()`

What are you doing in your:

```
// Insert parameters to complete the sql prepared statement
```

Are you using correctly the methods `ps.setString...` or whatever? Or are you just replacing the question marks? the second might be corrupting your query.

Comment: The code has the comment `// Insert parameters to complete the sql prepared statement` which seems to indicate this is being done, and in a comment it's stated that this happens with a query with no parameters. It wouldn't give this error anyway.

Comment: @AlexPoole My bad, deleting answer until some feedback comes.

Comment: @AlexPoole Well, I gave one more :P